# 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning how to program on the iOS operating system using the book "Head first iPhone and iPad development" (second edition).

[image: Screenshot]

When I try to compile the code from the book, I get the error that the use `release` keyword is not allowed in reference counting mode.

Do I have to explicitly release the memory in this case? If yes - how?

Comment: With ARC (introduced with iOS6 or iOS5), let's say it's managed just before the compilation.

Comment: With [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) enabled you don't have to, your book is probably a couple of years old.

Comment: Better get an up to date book, lots of things have changed.

Comment: Never call `release` manually if using `ARC`, but **for calling `autorelease` see:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/69640931/8740349

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Sounds like your book predates [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting).

You can develop an application with the same code if you disable ARC in the project settings:

[image: How to disable ARC]

But... ARC has been out for a while, and iOS changes fast. If the book doesn't mention ARC, it's a probably sign that it targets a version of the iOS SDK less than 5.0, which is not necessarily the best way to learn iOS development these days.

You can *roughly* translate to an ARC environment by just removing `[super dealloc]`, `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` from the code you see. But it's valuable to understand *why* those are there in the first place and why they're no longer necessary with ARC.

Answer (score 18):

You have enabled `Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)` in your project. That means that you can skip those `dealloc`, `release` and `autorelease` commands. :-)